# Im trying to make a string that a user has entered display in reverse

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me figure out what i am doing wrong? When i run it, it will not display.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function reverseMyString() {
      string = parseInt(prompt("Enter a String"));
      var str = string;
      var reverseStr = "";
      for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        reverseStr += str[i];
      document.write("Reversed String =" + reverseStr);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="reverseMyString()">Click here to reverse a String</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Unnecessary `parseInt` over entered string.

```
string = parseInt(prompt("Enter a String"));
         ^
```

Remove that call, and your logic will work as expected because will be treated as string rather than a number (Integer).

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function reverseMyString() {
      var str = prompt("Enter a String");
      var reverseStr = "";
      for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        reverseStr += str[i];
        
      document.write("Reversed String =" + reverseStr);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="reverseMyString()">Click here to reverse a String</button>
</body>

</html>
```

**Aside note:**

You don't need to re-assign the entered value to a new variable:

```
string = parseInt(prompt("Enter a String"));
var str = string;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: i knew it was something very simple i was missing thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a string you dont't have to parse it to an Integer.

This code below splits the string into an array, then reverses it with the built in reverse() function, then joins it again into a string.

```js
function reverseMyString() {
  var string = prompt("Enter a String");

  var reverseStr = string.split("").reverse().join("");

  console.log(reverseStr);

}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="reverseMyString()">Click here to reverse a String</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, just joined stackoverflow yesterday and I'm trying to learn fast how all of this works